# Equality between distribution functions on rationals

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F$ and $G$ be distribution functions. Assume that $F(q)=G(q)$ for $q$ a rational number.
Prove that $F(x)=G(x)$ for $x$ a real number.

I tried to take a sequence of rational numbers that converges to x but I cannot use the trick of changing the order of the limit because a distribution function is not continuous but right continuous.

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: *Hint.* For any $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists a sequence $(q_n)_{n\ge1}$ of rational numbers *decreasing* towards $x$.

Comment: Both $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are distribution functions, so right continuous is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a distribution function $F$ and $G$ are right-continuous. Let $x\in \Bbb R$. There exists a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ such that $q_n \in \Bbb Q$, $q_n \geq q_{n+1} \geq x$ and $q_n \to x$. Since $F$ and $G$ are right-continuous it holds
$$F(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}F(q_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} G(q_n ) = G(x)$$
for every $x\in \Bbb R$. We have used that $F(q_n) = G(q_n)$ for every $q_n$.